# Must I use Django's template language in templates?

Tags: python, django, web, django-forms, django-templates

Am I required to use Django's template language i.e:(HTML tags and Template lang. tags), or can I just use HTML, and stick in my {% csrf_token %} in each post form template?

Comment: for sending or showing data from views ? yes you have to follow it, or if you want make hand made forms in template? Follow this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Answer (score 1):

> Life is short - you need django forms!

and, `django's template tag` is wrong term for what you are talking about. I bet, you mean django forms.

you are not required to use django forms, but if you dont use them, you are missing the most powerful part of django. without it, you will have to validate all form data manuelly which can be tedious for bigger form requests.

just click on William's link and read on. Django is the best framework and has the best docs ever!

and btw, 
`{% csrf_token %}` is only needed for form data with `POST` method.

Answer (score 0):

No you are not required to use Django's template tags in your template. As long as the CSRF_TOKEN is in your form, your view can process it like any Django form.

However, Django's model form are you friend and they will save you a lot of time. They can also allow you to handle some logic related to the form in your forms.py, which can be conveniant and allow you not to repeat yourself.

See

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/

Answer (score 0):

{% csrf_token %} is used for security purpose. It's meaning is cross site reference forgery.

You have to write this in templete form post.

If you do not want to use  {% csrf_token %}, You have to use @csrf_exempt decorator above function 
 name as below:

```
 @csrf_exempt
 def test(request):
     print "yes"
```